# Grails java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

In my Bootstrap groovy I register a simple timer job to execute things in regular intervals. This timer then calls a function in a different service. Code of the function is below:

```
 def syncForReminderSms() {
        try {

            def settings = GeneralSetting.findAll([cache: true])[0];
            Integer daysToSync = settings.reminderSmsScanTimeInDays;

            def results = PatientenTermin.withCriteria {
                def now = new Date()
                and {
                    eq('reminderSmsSent', false)
                    between('startzeit', now, now + daysToSync)
                }
            }

            smsTemplatesService.sendReminderSms(results);
        }catch(e) {
            println ("ERROR for SMS reminder trigger: " + e);
        }
    }
```

When the timer is execute I Receive the error in the title. The try-catch never catches anything. The stacktrace points out to this line:

```
and {
```

I'm really stuck here. I have tried adding the runtime `'org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.0.RELEASE'` to the runtime dependecies which is one of the recommended ways to go. but this did not help.

Here is also the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest
        at grails.util.GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(GrailsWebUtil.java:55)
        at grails.util.GrailsWebUtil$bindMockWebRequest.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at com.digithurst.global.domain.SchedulerService.syncForReminderSms(SchedulerService.groovy:42)
        at com.digithurst.global.domain.SchedulerService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$15b81381.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at com.digithurst.global.domain.SchedulerService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5900970a.syncForReminderSms(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
        at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure5_closure18_closure19.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:175)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1068)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at BootStrap$_registerTimerJob_closure3.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:584)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at BootStrap$_registerTimerJob_closure3.doCall(BootStrap.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `spring-mock-<version>.jar` in your classpath. Add it and the error should go away.

if you are using maven add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How can I add this?

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the answer however I'm not using maven. I have my dependecies inside BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: @Jacob i do not know your groovy file so i can not help you with this

Comment: Eventually you pointed me to the sollution. Adding         compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-mock:2.0" to my dependecies did the trick.....